# Username converted to us-ascii (unix-style)

Tags: users

I want to convert unicode characters in user names to us-ascii. I.e my first name is Søren and my last name is Sjøstrøm. It should be converted to soren.sjostrom (unix style) as the user name. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to transliterate non-ASCII *European* characters (like those used in Nordic, German and French names), you can use the PHP function [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php). E.g:

```
$name = strtr($name,
   'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ',
   'AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYTsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuyty');
```

If you want to do romanization of a wider range of non-ASCII alphabets (cyrillic, greek, etc.) take a look at the contributed project [**Transliteration**](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration).

While this is specifically to transliterate file names to US-ASCII, at its core is UTF-8 normalization (based on UtfNormal.php from [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/)) and transliteration (based upon Sean M. Burke's [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm)).  You should be able to use the same libraries for romanization of names and other strings.

Comment: Thx, I will look into it :)